# How to manage a state 'collapsed' for each deeply nested node in a tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, tree

I have a complicated and dynamic data structure like so:

```
const tree = [
  {
    name: "Root Node",
    collapsed: true,
    nodes: [
      {
        name: "Node 1",
        collapsed: true,
        nodes: [
          {
            name: "Sub node"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Node 2",
        collapsed: true,
        nodes: [
          {
            name: "Sub node "
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Node 3",
        collapsed: true,
        nodes: [
          {
            name: "Sub node"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];`
```

I am setting this as the initial state of my component.

I am then rendering this state out as a hierarchy tree in the UI.

When I click the top level node I want to update the collapsed property in state to have it open up and show the next set of nodes.

The problem I am having is how do I call setState() and update this complicated data structure without causing mutation and doing some ugly stuff like tree[0].nodes[0].collapsed: false.

So I first tried setting state like this

```
handleClick(el, event) {
    this.setState({
        tree: this.findAndUpdateState(event.target.id).bind(this)
    });
}
```

So on the handleClick event of the node I call this which calls findAndUpdateState.

```
findAndUpdateState(id) {
    this.state.tree.map((node) => {
      //Map over the nodes somehow and find the node that needs its state updated using the ID?
      });
    });
}
```

I want to update the collapsed property of a node that has been attempted to be expanded.  But to do so I have to loop through all the state and then create a new copy of the state just to update that one property.  There must a nicer and simpler way that I am not thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a component `Node` with its own state `collapsed`:

```
class Node extends Component {
  state = {
    collapsed: true,
  }

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ collapsed: !prevState.collapsed }))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p onClick={this.toggle}>{this.props.node.name}</p>
        {!this.state.collapsed && (
          <div>{this.props.children}</div>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And create a parent component `Tree` that renders all the nodes recursively:

```
const TREE = [{ name: "Root Node", nodes: [...] }]

class Tree extends Component {
  renderNodesRecursively = parent => {
    return (
      <Node node={parent} key={parent.name}>
        {parent.nodes
          ? parent.nodes.map(node => this.renderNodesRecursively(node))
          : null
        }
      </Node>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return TREE.map(node => this.renderNodesRecursively(node))
  }
}
```

---

You will notice that the state of the children is lost each time you toggle the parent. It's "normal" since toggling the parent mounts/unmounts the children. If you want to avoid that, you can replace this code

```
{!this.state.collapsed && (
  <div>{this.props.children}</div>
)}
```

with

```
<div style={{ display: this.state.collapsed ? 'none' : 'block' }}>
  {this.props.children}
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like it might just hit the mark.  I am going to play around with this and see how I get on.  I should have thought to separate concerns and have separate components for each node.

Comment: @KerrFloyyd Did it help?

Answer (score 0):

React is pretty good at doing these sort of things.

I'm using the the Hooks in React, as I like them.. :)

Here is a working snippet below..

```js
const tree = [{"name":"Root Node","collapsed":true,"nodes":[{"name":"Node 1","collapsed":true,"nodes":[{"name":"Sub node"}]},{"name":"Node 2","collapsed":true,"nodes":[{"name":"Sub node "}]},{"name":"Node 3","collapsed":true,"nodes":[{"name":"Sub node"}]}]}];

const {useState} = React;


function TreeItem(props) {
  const {item} = props;
  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(item.collapsed);
  return <div className="item">
    <span onClick={() => setCollapsed(!collapsed)}>{item.name}</span>
    {!collapsed && item.nodes && 
      <div style={{paddingLeft: "1rem"}}>
        <TreeList list={item.nodes}/>
      </div>
    }
  </div>
}

function TreeList(props) {
  const {list} = props;
  return <div>{list.map(f => <TreeItem key={f.name} item={f}/>)}</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<TreeList list={tree}/>, document.querySelector('#mount'));
```

```css
.item {
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="mount"></div>
```